# GN: How to Transform (scale or rotate) relative to a "pivot point"?

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes

Often when modeling I will transform with the 3D Cursor as my [Pivot Point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/pivot_point/index.html). This is very useful, but I don't know what the equivalent method would be using **Geometry Nodes**.

How can I scale or rotate geometry in my node tree based on a known point? (The point could be specified by ID, for example.)

I imagine it's a simple thing to do, but how to do it with GN is not obvious to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you can control any center for rotation and scaling via an vector input.

[image]

In case of scaling, you can use this vector directly as *Center* for the node `Scale Elements`.

In case of rotation, you use the vector as *Center* in combination with the node `Rotate Vector` and `Set Position`.

---

If you want to rotate or scale instances, you can do so as follows:

[image]

Here I use the nodes `Rotate Instances` and `Scale Instances`, respectively, and a vector as *Center*.

Comment: Very handy! Thank you for including an explanation for instances too.